# Change upvote/downvote hover text on meta.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, up-votes

I am a regular user of the IT side of StackExchange (StackOverflow, Programmers, Serverfault etc). In these sites you upvote and downvote question based on whether you think the question shows research effort, is useful and clear

When using `meta.stackexchange.com` the guidance is a little different.

> Voting here works a bit differently from other Stack Exchange sites. On Meta Stack Overflow, voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness. Please don't be concerned if you receive downvotes – members of the community may simply disagree with your bug, feature request, support issue, or the nature of the discussion.

I was also reminded of this difference in my recent meta question

[Why is this a bad meta question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168480/why-is-this-a-bad-meta-question)

Should the hover-text on the `meta.stackexchange.com` sites be changed to reflect this difference?

Comment: dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168574/tooltip-for-down-votes-on-meta-stackoverflow which is dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites

Comment: @Bart Ah I searched meta for hovertext not tooltip. Fair enough. Lets get this closed!

Comment: @KevinBrydon No problem. Just knew about the dupe because a similar proposal had been made a mere 2 hours ago. :)

Comment: @Bart It's been bugging me since last nights debate so I thought I'd get the question out there this morning.